# Ignoring NA values when computing variogram in R?

Tags: r, null, variogram, gstat

I am trying to compute a variogram with the R [`gstat`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gstat) package:

```
 > variogram(yield_cleaned~1, data= newdf)
```

but it turns out:

```
 Error in .local(obj, ...) : NA values in coordinates
```

My dataset has `NA` values. How can I tell the program to ignore them?

Comment: I am wanting to perform interpolations in R. I am familiar with ArcGIS. @PolyGeo

Comment: Please always include that detail in your questions here.  I notice that you have not yet taken our 2-minute [Tour] to learn about this site's protocols.

Comment: Sorry my mistake...@PolyGeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove your `NA` in your `data frame` first using the function `na.omit` (see this: [remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-in-data-frame)) and then apply the `variogram` function.

```
# Load libraries
library('gstat')

# Example data
newdf <- data.frame("id" = 1:10,
                    "yield_cleaned" = runif(n = 10, min = 0, max = 1),
                    "x" =  sample(x = c(1:8, rep(NA,2)), size = 10),
                    "y" = sample(x = c(1:8, rep(NA,2)), size = 10)
                    )

# Remove NA rows
newdfNoNAs <- na.omit(object = newdf)

# Apply variogram function 
varData <- variogram(yield_cleaned~1, data = newdfNoNAs, locations = ~x+y)
```

I also suppose that make a variogram with no spatial information (`NA` values in your coordinates data) have no sense.

Comment: Please note that if the data is an sp class object, then this would be a issue because you would be removing row in the @data slot without removing the corresponding spatial element. This results in a mismatch between the slots in the object.

Comment: `newdf` returns 10 points and `newdfNoNAs` returns 6 points, Could you briefly explain why `varData` returns two points? @Guzmán

Comment: My data is in a data frame and `na.omit` has removed the corresponding coordinates as well.  My `varData <- variogram(yield_cleaned~1, data = newdfNoNAs, locations = ~lon+lat)` seems to take ages to run.  Any solution for this? My dataset has `203140 obs` after `na.omit()`. @Guzmán @Jeffrey Evans

Comment: @GoldenJiang `varData` returns two points because of the default `cutoff` value (the length of the diagonal of the box spanning the data is divided by three). Try for example: `varData <- variogram(yield_clea‌​ned~1, data = newdfNoNAs, locations = ~lon+lat, cutoff = 6)`

Comment: @GoldenJiang I had the same problem with a dataset of 287822 observations. You can just wait or clip your dataset by some extent and do it by parts.